# GeoSpatial Query not working for some location

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find nearest users (documents stored in mongo db) within radius of 10 using search query.

I have the Below data stored in **MongoDB**:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5afac246310390177e4d22b5")
"iRefUserId": "0",
"vFbId": "106493821",
"iCompanyId": "1",
"vName": "kanxxxx",
"vLastName": "xxxxxx",
"vEmail": "kxnxxx@gmail.com",
"vLoginId": "",
"vPassword": "$2y$12$ZiVWf2HQiidTERrK6DDGxu.LNVt0fBE9Yh3U0ddX711gaIeOTPEaS",
"eGender": "",
"Location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
       37.33233141, 
       -122.030189
    ]
 }
}
```

I am trying to find a record using `GeoSpatial` query on `"Location"` Object using `PHP/nodeJs`.

My search query is below:

```
{ "Location": { "$geoWithin": { "$center": [ [37.33233141, -122.030189], 10 ] } } }
```

A data (which i mentioned) didn't found by above query in mongodb.

Above query is working for some locations (stored in location object and also used in search query) like:

```
location-1: 23.0120896, 72.50335969999999
location-2: 49.249492, 70.398164
location-2: 22.094506, 48.800007
```

Please guide me to identify problem.

Comment: What problem? That `10` refers to the "radius" which means the "distance" from the queried point in which the other points can be. Those other polnts are "way outside" the specified radius. Note you store in GeoJSON, therefore the "radius" should be in **meters**.

Comment: A record using location "37.33233141, -122.030189" not found by query which i mentioned.

Comment: Or possibly the problem is using `$center` instead of `$centerSphere`. *"The query returns legacy coordinate pairs that are within the bounds of the circle. **The operator does not return GeoJSON objects**"*. So you really should be using `$centerSphere` here for actual geographic data, and of course to support GeoJSON.

Comment: I am trying to find nearest users (documents stored in mongo db) within radius of 10 using search query.

Comment: Please read the comment. You are using the wrong operator. `$centerSphere` is needed for GeoJSON. Distance is in **meters** with GeoJSON. And if you want "nearest" then you actually want `$nearSphere`.

Comment: Yes, i have tried but its not working